# I'm having problems with keyboard navigation using a jqxgrid with columns ordering and grouping activated

Tags: jqxgrid

I’m using jqxgrid, it is very powerfull, niceeeee grid,

But when using options "sortable: true" and "groupable: true" then key up and key down keyboard navigation doesn’t work correclty after make an ordering of any column.

When the grid is firts rendered the keyboard navigation works just fine, but if I activate a column ordering ( no grouping just ordering ) then the keyboard navigation don’t work as it should, I can not see the selected row anymore, it kind of jump randomly.
Here is a test case at JSfidle.net

`<http://jsfiddle.net/zemorango/z7cdkrfq/1/">`

[zemorango/z7cdkrfq/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/zemorango/z7cdkrfq/1/)

Thanks in advance
 jose